# Outer automorphism action on representations of $S_6$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, permutation-groups

Let $S_6$ be the symmetric group on 6 letters and let $\alpha \colon S_6 \to S_6$ be an outer automorphism (note that $S_6$ is the only permutation group that has an outer automorphism and that $\mathrm{Out}(S_6) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$). For any irreducible representation $\rho \colon S_6 \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ of $S_6$, the composition $\rho \circ \alpha \colon S_6 \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is also an irreducible representation.

Question: Is there a reference describing the action of this operation ($\rho \mapsto \rho \circ \alpha$) on the set of all irreducible representations of $S_6$ over $\mathbb{C}$ (that is on the set of partitions of 6)?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215298/three-involutions-on-the-set-of-6-box-young-diagrams/215329#215329

Comment: @MarkWildon: Dear Mark, thanks for your answer, but my question was actually about a reference where this action is described. Don't you know one by chance?

Comment: From the action on conjugacy classes it is very easy to get the action on characters, as I'm sure you know. But despite some searching (a few years ago) I have never seen this written down in a published paper.

Comment: @MarkWildon: Mark, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, notice that this operation preserves the dimension of the representation, this already considerably restricts things: the dimensions of the irreps. are 1,1,5,5,5,5,9,9,10,10,16.  The trivial rep. is fixed, thus the sign rep. must also be.  The 16-dimensional rep. $V_{(3,2,1)}$ is also fixed.

Next, since $\alpha$ maps conjugacy classes to conjugacy classes, it preserves the multiset of character values of $\rho$.  Checking this against a character table shows that the 9-dimensional reps. are also all fixed.  This does allow for the possibility that the 5-dimensional rep. $V_{(5,1)}$ is sent to $V_{(2,2,2)}$ and its conjugate $V_{(2,1,1,1,1)}$ is sent to $V_{(3,3)}$.  You can see that one of these pairs is swapped if and only if the other is by tensoring with the sign representation.  The 10-dimensional irreps. $V_{(4,1,1)}$ and $V_{(3,1,1,1)}$ may also be swapped.

EDIT:  After I have written this, Mark Wildon has linked to a question which subsumes this one.  His answer there, using an explicit description of $\alpha$'s action on conjugacy classes, is that all of the possible swaps I identified do in fact occur.

Comment: Dear Christian, thanks for your answer, but my question was actually about a reference where this action is described. Don't you know one by chance?

Comment: @Sasha The automorphism itself and its action on conjugacy classes is described well [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups#The_exceptional_outer_automorphism_of_S6).  Using arguments like mine or Mark Wildon's on the other question then determines the action on irreps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, there are some references in the Wikipedia article, maybe I will find something there.